# Doing math research without lecturing

Tags: research-process, mathematics, university, job

Is it possible to become a research mathematician without lecturing duties? I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: Perhaps you could let us know what kind of research you're interested in doing and where you're interested in doing it?  Not all mathematical research happens inside of academia.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is **yes**: there are research-only career pathways for mathematicians. One way of achieving this is to secure a job in a research-only institution, e.g. [Max-Planck Institute](https://www.mpg.de/institutes) in Germany, [Academy of Sciences](http://www.ras.ru/en/index.aspx) in Russia and other post-Soviet countries, or one of many government research labs / institutes in the USA.

Looking for a research-only career in a University can be much more challenging, if at all possible. This would usually imply buying off your teaching duties from a sequence of successful grants, and supervising many PhD students (which also involves a fair amount of teaching).

I can also recommend [this](http://aimath.org/news/postdoc/mathcareer.html) article.